Prove that an infinite sigma ring has countable disjoint sets
I’ve been working on an assignment in real analysis class, and this trapped me. I’ve found a related problem here, where it is $\sigma$-algebra that is discussed, but the argument doesn’t apply in $\sigma$-ring case. I want to use Hausdorff Maximal principle to show that there exist an infinite totally ordered set A by inclusion, and it is not hard to prove this. At first thought it seems easy to select countable disjoint sets from A, but it turns out not to be so easy and maybe not possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Why doesn't the linked proof work for $\sigma$ rings?

Let $X$ be a set and let $\mathcal{A}$ be an infinite $\sigma$-ring on $X$. Consider two cases.
Case $1$: $\mathcal{A}$ contains an inclusion-maximal member (that is, a member not properly contained in any other member).
In this case, let $B\in \mathcal{A}$ be an inclusion-maximal member. I claim that $A\subset B$ for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$. If this were not so, then for some $A\in \mathcal{A}$ with $A\not\subset B$, $B\subsetneq A\cup B\in\mathcal{A}$, contradicting maximality. Then $\mathcal{A}$ is an infinite $\sigma$-algebra on $B$, and the linked proof goes through.
Case $2$: $\mathcal{A}$ does not contain an inclusion-maximal member.
Pick $A_0\in \mathcal{A}$. Assuming $A_0\subsetneq A_1\subsetneq \ldots\subsetneq A_n$, $A_i\in\mathcal{A}$ have been chosen, then since $A_n$ is not maximal, there exists $A_n\subsetneq A_{n+1}\in\mathcal{A}$. Define $B_n=A_{n+1}\setminus A_n\in\mathcal{A}$ and note that $(B_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ are pairwise disjoint.

Thanks a lot for your help
